# Problemas con generación de código

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, dbeaver

Tengo un problema a la hora de generar el código en la tabla equipo, al generar el código no toma el ultimo id insertado, se repite siempre el mismo código a pesar de que el id del registro y del producto si se ingresa bien y cambia en cada ejecución. Quisiera saber que estoy que estoy haciendo mal por no continuar la secuencia de la inserción. Lo que he desarrollado hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%.%.%.%` PROCEDURE `db-cosmo-catalogos`.`sp_insertar_datos`(
                     IN evento VARCHAR(255),
                     IN cantidad INT,
                     IN nombre VARCHAR(255),
                     IN ID_Catalogo INT,
                     IN ID_Bodega INT,
                     IN codOrden VARCHAR(255),
                     IN codigoUsuario VARCHAR(255),
                     IN modelo VARCHAR(255),
                     IN descripcion VARCHAR(255),
                     IN foto LONGTEXT,
                     IN bloqueaDescuento INT,
                     IN ID_Empresa INT,
                     IN aud_idempresa INT,
                     IN aud_idusuarioregistra INT,
                     IN fecharegistra DATETIME,
                     IN aud_pc VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE idProducto INT;
                                           
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTIO
BEGIN
-- En caso de error, se ejecuta el ROLLBACK para revertir los cambios
ROLLBACK;
-- Puedes agregar aquí más acciones en caso de error si es necesario
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error en la transacción';
END;

START TRANSACTION;
   
-- Insertar en la primera tabla y obtener el ID generado
INSERT INTO tbl_catalogo_equipo (
               Equ_codigo,
               Equ_codigoUsuario,
               Equ_nombre,
               Equ_modelo, 
               Equ_descripcion, 
               Equ_foto,
               ID_Empresa,
               ID_Catalogo,
               Equ_bloqueaDescuento,
               aud_idempresa,
               aud_idusuarioregistra,
               aud_fecharegistra,
               aud_estadoregistro,
               aud_pc)
               VALUES (
                CONCAT('E', LPAD(lastEquId, 5, '0')), 
-- Generar     Equ_codigo,
               codigoUsuario, 
               nombre, 
               modelo, 
               descripcion, 
               foto,
               ID_Empresa,
               ID_Catalogo,
               bloqueaDescuento,
               aud_idempresa,
               aud_idusuarioregistra,
               fecharegistra,
               'ACT',
               aud_pc);
                                           
-- Obtener el ID generado
               SET idProducto = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                                           
-- Insertar en la segunda tabla utilizando el ID generado
               INSERT INTO tbl_registros (
                      Mon_evento,
                      Mon_cantidad,
                      Mon_nombre, 
                      ID_Producto,
                      ID_Catalogo, 
                      ID_Bodega,
                      CodOrden, 
                      aud_pc,
                      aud_idempresa,
                      aud_idusuarioregistra,
                      aud_fecharegistra,
                      aud_estadoregistro)
                      VALUES (
                      evento, 
                      cantidad, 
                      nombre, 
                      idProducto, 
                      ID_Catalogo, 
                      ID_Bodega, 
                      codOrden,
                      aud_pc, 
                      aud_idempresa,
                      aud_idusuarioregistra,
                      fecharegistra, 
                      'ACT');

                      COMMIT;
                      END
```

asi esta definida la tabla de equipo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_catalogo_equipo` (
  `ID_Equipo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Equ_codigo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Equ_nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Equ_modelo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Equ_descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Equ_foto` longtext,
  `ID_Empresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idempresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idusuarioregistra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idusuariomodifica` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aud_fecharegistra` datetime NOT NULL,
  `aud_fechamodifica` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `aud_pc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `aud_estadoregistro` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `Equ_bloqueaDescuento` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ID_Catalogo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Equ_codigoUsuario` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Equipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

y asi la de registro:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_registros` (
  `ID_Monitoreo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_Producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodOrden` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Mon_evento` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Mon_cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idempresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_estadoregistro` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idusuarioregistra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aud_idusuariomodifica` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aud_fecharegistra` datetime NOT NULL,
  `aud_fechamodifica` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `aud_pc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ID_Catalogo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mon_nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_Bodega` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Monitoreo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Serias tan amable de colocar la definición de tu tabla? Una duda que me surge es, siempre vas a insertar en ambas tablas al mismo tiempo?

Comment: si, necesito que se registre en una y luego tomar el id de esa para registrar en la segunda

puse la definicion de las tablas en la pregunta